# Why do I need to call a function but not a method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

in Node.js I have this code:

```
console.log('starting');


function sayHello() {
    console.log('HEllo!!');
}


setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('inside of callback');
}, 1000);

console.log('finishing app');
```

Why if I run through the terminal the (App) file it displays the result of the setTimeout function but not the sayHello? After all, I did not call the setTimeout function either!
Moreover, if then I store the setTimeout function in a variable like

```
var x = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('inside of callback');
}, 1000);
```

the function is called automatically as well! Why?

Comment: you never call `sayHello` ... and the two setTimeout's both call the callback after 1 second ... the difference is, you're saving the timeout id in `x` in the second code - you're not storing the function, you're storing the result of calling setTimeout - which is the timeout id

Comment: `I did not call the setTimeout function either` you did - `setTimeout()` *calls* the function. `then I store the setTimeout function` no, you *execute* the function and store the *result* of it. I'm also not sure what this question has to do with functions and methods - you only have functions here.

Comment: Because setTimeout  is a method

Comment: if you do `x = sayHello()` you would get the same result, though

Comment: Read the documentation of `setTimeout`: the function you pass to it will be executed by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no link with function or method here. It's about `declaration` and `call`.

When you do :

```
function sayHello() {
    console.log('HEllo!!');
}
```

You declare a function `sayHello` that won't be called. To call it, you need to do `sayHello();` after declare it.

When you use `setTimeout()`, you are calling a built-in function **already declared** for you by JavaScript. To know how to use the function that is already declared, you need to check a documentation of the function. Example : [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) (part syntax).

Note : Every function in JavaScript is attached to an object, so every function is a method. `setTimeout`, for example, is attached to the global object (in browser, it's `window`, in Node it's `global`). Your `sayHello()` function will be also attached to her scope.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of setTimeout is something like (this is only a mock implementation):

```
function setTimeout(callback, interval, ....args) {
    // wait for `interval` time to pass
    callback(...args);
}
```

As you can see,  `setTimeout` is a function which takes a function(`callback` in the above example) as a parameter, and calls that function after `interval` time has passed.